# How to change change and track boolean state of each element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Im trying to make it so that when a `TouchableHighlight` is pressed in react native it goes from one colour to another. I have state that is set to false and changes when the button is pressed. However this changes the colour for all elements in the map rather than for each item individually. Is there a way to update the state for each element independently?
Here is my code:

```
function OnboardingVibes() {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 40}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 22, color: '#FFF', marginBottom: 16}}>Vibes</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {vibes.map((vibe) => {
            return (
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setPressed(true)} style={{backgroundColor: pressed ? '#DDD' : '#4D2C5B', margin: 4, borderRadius: 4}} key={`vibe-${vibe}`}>
                  <Text style={styles.vibeButton}>{vibe}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            )
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to move the state down so you could have individual states. When the state is `true` at the top-level, all child components will receive the same state.

```
function TouchableVibe({vibe}) {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={() => setPressed(true)}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: pressed ? "#DDD" : "#4D2C5B",
        margin: 4,
        borderRadius: 4,
      }}
    >
      <Text style={styles.vibeButton}>{vibe}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

function OnboardingVibes() {
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, color: "#FFF", marginBottom: 16 }}>
        Vibes
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        {vibes.map((vibe) => (
          <TouchableVibe key={`vibe-${vibe}`} vibe={vibe} />
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works great, my only issue is how would I then add each vibe pressed into an array of vibes? Ive tried to add a state array on touchableVibes however this doesnt seem to work? Any help further be great!

Comment: If you have the array state in `TouchableVibe` you'd only be tracking one, so now you have to lift that array state up and then pass the handler back into `TouchableVibe`. Imagine this tree `OnboardingVibe -> TouchableVibe`, states in the inner level (right) cannot be seen by the parent (left). But left can be seen by the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(vibes.map(e=>false));
{vibes.map((vibe, index) => {
           return (
               <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
let new_Pressed =vibes.map(e=>false)
    new_pressed[index]=true;
setPressed(new_pressed);
}} 
style={{backgroundColor: pressed[index] 
                ? '#DDD' 
                : '#4D2C5B',
                margin: 4, borderRadius: 4}} key={`vibe-${vibe}`}>
                 <Text style={styles.vibeButton}>{vibe}</Text>
               </TouchableHighlight>
           )
         })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in a boolean to the state, pass in the `id/vibe` instead, and then in your conditional logic within the `map` you can determine if that single item is the same as the one you've clicked.

```
function OnboardingVibes() {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState('');
  return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 40}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 22, color: '#FFF', marginBottom: 16}}>Vibes</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {vibes.map((vibe) => {
            return (
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setPressed(vibe)} style={{backgroundColor: pressed === vibe ? '#DDD' : '#4D2C5B', margin: 4, borderRadius: 4}} key={`vibe-${vibe}`}>
                  <Text style={styles.vibeButton}>{vibe}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            )
          })}
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works, however only for one at once, id like to do this for each vibe and so it ends up a few of them being highlighted rather than one at once. How would it be best to do this?